# error involving JSON data with xcode via swift

Tags: php, mysql, json, xcode

I am in the process of making an app that retrieves data from a mysql database.

I have gotten this to work as it displayed my information where I wanted.

I wake up the next day and my website is down so i make another one but my code stopped working and gives me this error:

```
    Data downloaded
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}
```

i know the error happens on the func parseJSON becuase i took off the "self.parseJSON" and it downloaded the data without displaying the error but it still doesnt display.

here is the code where the error is happening:

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, task: NSURLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: NSError?) {
    if error != nil {
        print("Failed to download data")
    }else {
        print("Data downloaded")
       self.parseJSON()
    }

}

func parseJSON() {
    var jsonResult: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    do{
        jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(self.data, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as! NSMutableArray

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }

    var jsonElement: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    let pools: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    for(var i = 0; i < jsonResult.count; i++)
    {
        jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary

        let pool = PoolModel()

        //the following insures none of the JsonElement values are nil through optional binding
        if let Date = jsonElement["Date"] as? String,
            let PH = jsonElement["PH"] as? String,
            let CH = jsonElement["CH"] as? String,
            let Alk = jsonElement["Alk"] as? String,
            let CYA = jsonElement["CYA"] as? String,
            let TEMP = jsonElement["TEMP"] as? String
            {
                pool.Date = Date
                pool.PH = PH
                pool.CH = CH
                pool.Alk = Alk
                pool.CYA = CYA
                pool.TEMP = TEMP
            }

            pools.addObject(pool)

        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.delegate.itemsDownloaded(pools)
        })
    }
}
```

Did I delete something from my code or could it be the php file where I getting the data?

```
  Data downloaded
    JSON:
    <3c68746d 6c3e3c62 6f64793e 3c736372 69707420 74797065 3d227465 78742f6a 
           61766173 63726970 74222073 72633d22 2f616573 2e6a7322 203e3c2f 73637269 70743e3c 73637269 70743e66 756e6374 696f6e20 746f4e75 6d626572 73286429
```

7b766172 20653d5b 5d3b642e 7265706c 61636528 2f282e2e 292f672c 66756e63 74696f6e 
2864297b 652e7075 73682870 61727365 496e7428 642c3136 29297d29 3b726574 75726e20 657d6675 6e637469 6f6e2074 6f486578 28297b66 6f722876 61722064 3d5b5d2c 643d313d 3d617267 756d656e 74732e6c 656e6774 68262661 7267756d 656e7473 5b305d2e 636f6e73 74727563 746f723d 3d417272 61793f61 7267756d 656e7473 5b305d3a 61726775 6d656e74 732c653d 22222c66 3d303b66 3c642e6c 656e6774 683b662b 2b29652b 3d283136 3e645b66 5d3f2230 223a2222 292b645b 665d2e74 6f537472 696e6728 3136293b 72657475 726e2065 2e746f4c 6f776572 43617365 28297d76 61722061 3d746f4e 756d6265 72732822 66363535 62613964 30396131 31326434 39363863 36333537 39646235 39306234 22292c62 3d746f4e 756d6265 72732822 39383334 34633265 65653836 63333939 34383930 35393235 38356234 39663830 22292c63 3d746f4e 756d6265 72732822 34333331 39653035 63313431 63366231 64356165 62343931 33636238 66356232 22293b64 6f63756d 656e742e 636f6f6b 69653d22 5f5f7465 73743d22 2b746f48 65782873 6c6f7741 45532e64 65637279 70742863 2c322c61 2c622929 2b223b20 65787069 7265733d 5468752c 2033312d 4465632d 33372032 333a3535 3a353520 474d543b 20706174 683d2f22 3b20646f 63756d65 6e742e63 6f6f6b69 653d2272 65666572 7265723d 222b6573 63617065 28646f63 756d656e 742e7265 66657272 6572293b 206c6f63 6174696f 6e2e6872 65663d22 68747470 3a2f2f70 6f6f6c63 616c632e 62796574 686f7374 31312e63 6f6d2f73 65727669 63652e70 68703f63 6b617474 656d7074 3d31223b 3c2f7363 72697074 3e3c6e6f 73637269 70743e54 68697320 73697465 20726571 75697265 73204a61 76617363 72697074 20746f20 776f726b 2c20706c 65617365 20656e61 626c6520 4a617661 73637269 70742069 6e20796f 75722062 726f7773 6572206f 72207573 65206120 62726f77 73657220 77697468 204a6176 61736372 69707420 73757070 6f72743c 2f6e6f73 63726970 743e3c2f 626f6479 3e3c2f68 746d6c3e>
        Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}

Also the php file is working fine on the website as it displays the info online

here is a link to that file

[poolcalc php](http://poolcalc.byethost11.com/service.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update answer for updated question:

The JSON hex data is the following string decoded as UTF-8:

`<tmll<booy><<criit ttpe==texx/jaaascciptt srr="//es..s"  </ssripp><ssripp>fuuctiin ttNummerssd){{ar  =[]]d.rrplaae(//..))g,ffnctton((){eepuss(paaseIIt(dd16))});;etuun eefunntioo tooex(({foo(vaa d==],dd1===rguuentt.leegthh&arrumeets[[].ccnsttucttr===rraa?arrumeets[[]:aagummntsse="",f==;f<<.leegthhf+++e+==16>>[f]]"0""""))d[ff.tootriig(11);rrturr e..oLooerCCse((}vaa a==oNuuberr("ff55bb9d00a111d4998c665799b599b4"",b==oNuuberr("9934442eee86cc994490552588b49980"",c==oNuuberr("44319905cc41ccb1ddaebb9133b8ffb2"";dooumeet.ccokii="__tess="++oHee(sllwAEE.deerypp(c,,,a,,))++; eepirrs=TTu,  1-DDc-33 23355::5 GGT;  athh/";;doccmenn.cookiee"reeerrrr=""esccpe((ocuuenttreffrree);  ocaaionnhree="hhtp::/poolcaac.bbethhst11.coo/seevicc.phh?ckktteept==";<<scrrpt>>nossripp>Thhs sste  equuressJavvscrrpt  o wwrk,,pleese  nabbe JJvassripp innyouu brrwsee orruseea bbowssr wwth  avaacriit ssppoot<//oscciptt</bbdy>>/httl>`

That is mangled html not JSON.

Comment: thank you, here is the json code . I added it at the top.

Comment: I am still the issue. I downloaded the xcode project of what I was basing my app on and it also gives the error. The project works and it works for others. It worked for me a couple days ago, now it isnt. I dont know what on my laptop is causing the json data to be weird like that

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason that I am still trying to figure out, I at least know the source. I thought it was the code in my xcode project. Using PostMan on chrome, I put in the link http://poolcalc.byethost11.com/service.php and it sends pack this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
    <script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f
        <d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("43319e05c141c6b1d5aeb4913cb8f5b2");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; document.cookie="referrer="+escape(document.referrer); location.href="http://poolcalc.byethost11.com/service.php?ckattempt=2";
        </script>
        <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
    </body>
</html>
```

I dont understand why its doing that but that would be why the program doesnt like it.